# jQuery a[href=#/example] does not select all matching anchors - cross-browser issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser, sizzle

So I'm trying to get jQuery to make the following selection:

```
$("a[href=#/example]")
```

and I have an anchor `<a href="#/example">ex</a>`.

When I try this selector out in chrome, IE8, FF, or other browsers it works fine, but when I goto test it in IE6/7, and other older browsers, the selector doesn't work because the browser interprets the anchor's href attribute as `http://example.com/#/example`

What's a graceful way to solve this issue for all browsers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [ends-with attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/):

```
$("a[href$=#/example]")
```

Comment: Flawless, easy, and elegant. Thank you. (10-minute wait to accept answer)